# No response when download button is clicked

Tags: android

I have a download button in my app which when pressed should download files from parse.com where I have stored the files. But when the button is clicked nothing happens the progress dailog disappear in fraction of seconds and the download is not performed.

The code

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity
{

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
String heading;
String subHeading;
String levelImg;
String apiImg;
String apiText;
String descImgOne;
String descImgTwo;
String codeText;
ImageLoader imgloader = new ImageLoader(this);

private static String file_url;



private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ImageView my_image;
// Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    heading= i.getStringExtra("heading");
        subHeading = i.getStringExtra("subheading");
    levelImg = i.getStringExtra("levelimg");
        apiImg = i.getStringExtra("apiimg");
        apiText = i.getStringExtra("apitext");
        descImgOne = i.getStringExtra("descimgone");
    descImgTwo = i.getStringExtra("descimgtwo");
        codeText = i.getStringExtra("codetext");
    file_url = i.getStringExtra("download");






    TextView headingtxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.singleitemheading);
    TextView subheadingtxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.singleitemsubheading);
    TextView apitxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.singleitemviewapitext);
    TextView codetxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleitemviewcodetext);

    ImageView level =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.levelimg);
    ImageView api =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.singleitemviewapiimg);
    ImageView descone =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionimgone);
    ImageView desctwo =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionimgtwo);



    Button downloadbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singleitemviewButton);

    headingtxt.setText(heading);
    subheadingtxt.setText(subHeading);
    apitxt.setText(apiText);
    codetxt.setText(codeText);

    imgloader.DisplayImage(levelImg, level);
    imgloader.DisplayImage(apiImg, api);
    imgloader.DisplayImage(descImgOne, descone);
    imgloader.DisplayImage(descImgTwo, desctwo);



    downloadbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String downurl = file_url;

            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(downurl);
        }
    });

}  

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{



    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;

        try{


         URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);

        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/download/downloadedfile.png");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();

        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());

    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Updating progress bar
 * */
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

/**
 * After completing background task
 * Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String downurl) {
    // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
    dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);


}

}
 }
```

Comment: Maybe there are some logs?

Comment: @AntonShkurenko No there is nothing

Comment: Try to debug, also put some logs. Maybe file is empty, so it downloads nothing?

Comment: @AntonShkurenko I did debug there is no problem and even the file is present other it would crash saying nullpointerexception in logcat

Comment: Try to debug network with something kinda this (https://www.charlesproxy.com/), maybe it can help you to see your how do your app communicate with the network.

Comment: Have you double-checked the value of `downurl` when passing it to the AsyncTask? How about `lenghtOfFile`? Do you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah I do have permissions setup in the manifest and the values of downurl is set as file_url where file_url = I.getStringExtra"download");

Comment: Are you sure there are valid values?

Comment: I meant the value. What's the actual String for `file_url`?

Comment: @AntonShkurenko Yeah they are correct values.. I have seen the example from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Comment: Well, the only place you dismiss the Dialog is in `onPostExecute()`, so it's reaching that method. Keep debugging your `doInBackground()` method. You've not given us enough information to diagnose the specific problem in the code you're running.

Comment: @MikeM. Ran the debugger again can't find any problem

Comment: I just ran a test AsyncTask to retrieve the image from the link given in that example. I had no problem. If you can't get your debugger to work for you, then start manually debugging; e.g., add a bunch of Log prints throughout the `doInBackground()`, and see where it trips up.

Comment: @MikeM. But that example worked for me fine

Comment: Then the problem must be in whatever you changed. We can't really help you any more, since you seem to be unwilling to share actual debugging info and data with us.

Comment: @MikeM. Been trying to figure out what is wrong from a week. Will try to manually debug as you said. Will let you know. Thanks very much

Comment: One last thing you should check: make sure `"/sdcard/download/downloadedfile.png"` points to a valid location in your external storage.

Comment: @MikeM. Ya ya it does point to the correct location